# Knitting rmarkdown document to pdf with file path not encoded in utf-8

Tags: r, utf-8, r-markdown, xelatex

```
Error message:
错误: LaTeX failed to compile 121234567.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See 121234567.log for more info.
此外: Warning messages:
1: In xfun::read_utf8(f2) :
  The file C:\Users\中文字符串\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSa7Fbe\stderr183065c81d05 is not encoded in UTF-8. These lines contain invalid UTF-8 characters: 1, 2, 3, 7
2: In xfun::read_utf8(f2) :
  The file C:\Users\中文字符串\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSa7Fbe\stderr183029983419 is not encoded in UTF-8. These lines contain invalid UTF-8 characters: 1, 2, 3, 7
停止执行
```

It is probably caused by the none utf-8 characters in the file path.(username on Windows)

The file 121234567.tex is created by knitting the template rmarkdown given in RStudio.

```
SessionInfo:
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                              
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tinytex_0.25    forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.3     purrr_0.3.3    
 [6] readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.0.0     tibble_2.1.3    ggplot2_3.2.1   tidyverse_1.3.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_0.2.5 xfun_0.11        haven_2.2.0      lattice_0.20-38 
 [5] colorspace_1.4-1 vctrs_0.2.3      generics_0.0.2   htmltools_0.4.0 
 [9] yaml_2.2.0       rlang_0.4.2      pillar_1.4.2     glue_1.3.1      
[13] withr_2.1.2      DBI_1.1.0        dbplyr_1.4.2     modelr_0.1.5    
[17] readxl_1.3.1     lifecycle_0.1.0  munsell_0.5.0    gtable_0.3.0    
[21] cellranger_1.1.0 rvest_0.3.5      evaluate_0.14    knitr_1.26      
[25] fansi_0.4.0      broom_0.5.2      Rcpp_1.0.3       scales_1.1.0    
[29] backports_1.1.5  jsonlite_1.6     fs_1.3.1         hms_0.5.2       
[33] digest_0.6.23    stringi_1.4.3    grid_3.6.1       cli_2.0.0       
[37] tools_3.6.1      magrittr_1.5     lazyeval_0.2.2   crayon_1.3.4    
[41] pkgconfig_2.0.3  xml2_1.2.2       reprex_0.3.0     lubridate_1.7.4 
[45] assertthat_0.2.1 rmarkdown_2.3    httr_1.4.1       rstudioapi_0.10 
[49] R6_2.4.1         nlme_3.1-140     compiler_3.6.1
```

Comment: That's a really old R version, and `xfun` is also looking pretty old.  Maybe updating R to 4.0.3, and updating all of your packages would help.

Comment: You can try updating like suggested above. Also if you go to `File` -> `reopen with encoding` and then pick your encoding type

Comment: The error message complains that _file content_ isn't UTF-8 (rather than about characters in the file path).

Comment: @JosefZ:  since the filename is `stderr183065c81d05`, it's likely where `rmarkdown` (or a package it uses) puts error messages; those could contain the filename.